# Clickable moving buttons in android

Tags: android, button

I'm trying to create an app in android which will spawn a button at top of the screen with a random x-possition, have it move downwards at a constant pace and when I click it disappear, I'm fairly confident in my abilities to do most of this by myself but the one problem I can't seem to work around is that I want to be able to click the button all the time while it is moving, I've found how to change the possition of the button but it is still fixed while I want it to follow the visual button. not sure if what I'm saying makes sense but if so, if anyone could help me out that would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance

```
public void animate() {
    starButton.startAnimation(anim);
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    boolean bool = true;
    int i = 0;
    while(bool) {
        long cur = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if(cur - start >= 50) {
            float posToGo = starButton.getY() + 20;
            starButton.setY(posToGo);
            i++;
            start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            if(i > 40) {
                bool = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried running it in a constant loop where I, once 50 ms have passed, run buttonName.setY(buttonName.getY + 20) so to move it forward bit by bit for x times and then exiting the loop, but all this result in is moving the actual button down by 20*x pixels before even starting the animation, I was unable to copy my code into the topic at the time I wrote it but I will do it now (It's very messy but should give an idea of what I mean and what I want)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the old animation api, use the new one with ObjectAnimators and stuff. 
Check out this tutorial : http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidAnimation/article.html

Edit: clarification...the old api didn't move anything, it was just drawing the image of the view at a different position, but the view never changed position, the new one really changes position and other properties.